# PHP while loop within while loop only returning limited rows

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting back into PHP and MySQL coding and I have a search page that returns certain rows in a table using 2 while loops.

The first while loop searches the database and the second searches a 2nd DB for matches on a registration to determine the type of equipment. The script is working, however, when the first while loop returns more than 2 results, the 2nd while loop only displays the first 2 returns on the equipment, any help would be welcomed.

```
$connect = mysql_connect("$dbhost", "$dbuname", "$dbpass") or die("Couldn't connect.");
$db = mysql_select_db($db_name, $connect) or die("Couldn't select database.");
$query = "SELECT * FROM `db1` WHERE `dest_id` =$ap ORDER BY video_date DESC, operator_name, operator_tail ASC";
$result = mysql_query($query,$connect) or mysql_error();

while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $row_color = ($row_count % 2) ? $color1 : $color2;
    $time_update = $r[video_date];
    $str_time = date('M. d, Y', $time_update);

    echo ("<tr><td bgcolor='$row_color'>&nbsp;<a href='$server?al=$r[operator_id]'>$r[operator_name]</a>
           </td><td bgcolor='$row_color' align='center'>&nbsp;<a href='$r[operator_ICAO]$r[flight_num]' target='_blank'>$r[flight_num]</a>
           </td><td bgcolor='$row_color'>&nbsp;<a href='$r[operator_tail]' target='_blank'>$r[operator_tail]</a>
           </td><td bgcolor='$row_color' align='center'>&nbsp;<a href='$r[video_url]' target='_blank'>$r[video_url]</a>
           </td><td bgcolor='$row_color' align='center'>");

    $connect2 = mysql_connect("$dbhost", "$dbuname", "$dbpass") or die("Couldn't connect.");
    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM `plane` WHERE `plane_id` =$r[plane_id]";
    $result2 = mysql_query($query2,$connect2) or mysql_error();

    while ($q = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
        echo ("&nbsp;$q[plane_type]");
    }

    mysql_close($connect2);
    echo (" </td><td bgcolor='$row_color' align='center'>&nbsp;$str_time
            </td><td bgcolor='$row_color' align='center'>&nbsp;<a href='$server?ap=$r[dest_id]'>$r[dest_name]
            </td><td bgcolor='$row_color' align='center'>&nbsp;$r[vtype_name]
            </td> </tr>");
    $row_count++;
}
mysql_close($connect);
```

Comment: 1) you don't have to connect to db again. 2) you should look into using either PDO or mysqli_* as mysql_* has been deprecated

Comment: you're not selecting database on $connect2, and as @ElefantPhace said and as you're returning to php, update your knowledge you should start using mysqli or PDO as mysql_* functions are deprecated

Comment: I think he meant a second table, not necessarily a second database, but I could be wrong...

Comment: well he doesn't need 2 db connections, but he's using 2, and on the second connection, connection2, he's not selecting and database, he's connecting then querying directly

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i see a few concerns here. For one mysql_fetch_array will return an unassociative array unless your system is setup to return the type MYSQL_BOTH. I would advise rewriting the script to mysqli like this:

```
<?php
$connect = new mysqli("$dbhost", "$dbuname", "$dbpass","$db_name");
$connect->connect_errno ? die("Couldn't connect.") : null ;

$query = "SELECT * FROM `db1` WHERE `dest_id` =$ap ORDER BY video_date DESC, operator_name, operator_tail ASC";
$result = $connect->query($query);

if(!$results->errno):

while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $row_color = ($row_count % 2) ? $color1 : $color2;
    $time_update = $r[video_date];
    $str_time = date('M. d, Y', $time_update);

    echo ("<tr><td bgcolor='$row_color'>&nbsp;<a href='$server?al=$r[operator_id]'>$r[operator_name]</a>
           </td><td bgcolor='$row_color' align='center'>&nbsp;<a href='$r[operator_ICAO]$r[flight_num]' target='_blank'>$r[flight_num]</a>
           </td><td bgcolor='$row_color'>&nbsp;<a href='$r[operator_tail]' target='_blank'>$r[operator_tail]</a>
           </td><td bgcolor='$row_color' align='center'>&nbsp;<a href='$r[video_url]' target='_blank'>$r[video_url]</a>
           </td><td bgcolor='$row_color' align='center'>");

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `plane` WHERE `plane_id` =$r[plane_id]";

    if($result2 = $connect->query($query)):
        while ($q = $result2->fetch_assoc($result2)) {
            echo ("&nbsp;$q[plane_type]");
        }

        echo (" </td><td bgcolor='$row_color' align='center'>&nbsp;$str_time
                </td><td bgcolor='$row_color' align='center'>&nbsp;<a href='$server?ap=$r[dest_id]'>$r[dest_name]
                </td><td bgcolor='$row_color' align='center'>&nbsp;$r[vtype_name]
                </td> </tr>");
        $row_count++;
    endif;
}
endif;
$connect->close();
```

Also if you can avoid the nested loop `Complexity (N * M)` aka O(N<sup>2</sup>) . I would rewrite the SQL statement to use `INNER JOIN` to get all the results at once.

Hope that helps you find your solution and helps your script run faster.

**UPDATE**

here is the code that works for your issue. I didn't fully updated everything to optimize it but this will establish a baseline for you:

[Files is here](http://stackoverflow.myopenbeta.com/22055388/file.txt)

[Working Example here](http://stackoverflow.myopenbeta.com/22055388/)

Comment: Thanks for the above, I'll give it a whirl.

As I said, I've been out of the coding loop for a while and just used an old old scripting I had from several years back. I am using one database but different tables, again, thanks for the above. I shall report back.

Comment: Yeah, still stuck as it seems the mysqli isn't working right, but it is in the php config. Here is the full code with obvious stuff removed:
http://aircraftvideos.net/file.txt

Comment: Can you upload the an sql dump. This will help to track where the issue is.

Comment: here's a quick dump of a limited number of rows, but shows the DB:
http://www.aircraftvideos.net/file2.txt

Comment: I added links to the top that you can follow to see a working copy of the code as well as the downloadable file.

Comment: If this solution has worked for you please vote up and mark as the best answer. Thanks!